# Is there a simpler way to handle graphql mutation in vue?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo-client, gql, vue-apollo

Does anyone know of a simpler way to consume graphql on the frontend specifically in vuejs with apollo? From what I've seen It seems handling CRUD functionality is a lot more complicated compared to using a rest style api...

For example:
here is a quick example I wrote utilizing apollo to demonstrate my issue with gql mutations

```
//vue data looks something like this
data() {
     return {
          contactData: {
              firstName: "",
              lastName: "",
              email: ""
          }
     }
},
methods: {
        createContact(){
          this.$apollo.mutate({
              mutation: gql`mutation createContact($firstName: String!, $lastName: String!, $email: String!){
                createContact(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, email: $email) {
                  id,
                  firstName,
                  lastName,
                  email}
              }`,
              variables:{
                ...this.contactData
              }
            }
          )
        },
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this mutation specifically these 2 lines? I find it redundant and time consuming to have to define all those variables/query fields in every mutation

```
mutation: gql`mutation createContact($firstName: String!, $lastName: String!, $email: String!){
                createContact(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, email: $email) {
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline your mutations. So basically something like: `src/graphql/mutations/createContact.graphql`. Then you can import them into your component:

```js
import createContactMutation from 'src/graphql/mutations/createContact.graphql'

// other component stuff
methods: {
  createContact(){
    this.$apollo.mutate({
      mutation: createContactMutation,
      variables: this.contactData
    })
  },
}
```